# Does this expression invokes undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior

This started from a joke:

> Interviewer: What is the difference between C and C++?
>    Candidate: ONE

My question is whether the expressions `abs(C++ - C)` and `abs(C - C++)` invokes undefined behavior or not?

Comment: This is not only undefined but also unspecified behavior since the order of evaluation of sub-expressions is not specified.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the type of `C`, but at the best (a user defined
type, where `++` is a function), it is unspecified whether the
second `C` is evaluated before or after the evaluation of
`C.operator++`.

Of course, for a built-in type, the expression is undefined
behavior, and for a user defined type, the final results will
also depend on how the user defined `operator++`, as well as the
compiler dependent order of evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is undefined behaviour. The compiler will not make any promises on when the increment will happen if you reuse the same variable in the statement.

Comment: It's only undefined behavior if `C` has a built-in type.  Otherwise, it's only unspecified (and with a limited set of possible values---supposing that the user defined `operator++` is deterministic).

Answer (score 0):

yes this is UB. From C99, Section 6.5

> An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies
>   computation of a value
>
> Except as specified later (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and
>   comma operators), **the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the
>   order in which side effects take place are both unspecified**

Therefore the is no guarantee in the express `C++ - C` when the post increment is executed.